# JXBrowser, waiting for window.location = another url

Tags: jxbrowser

I have to submit a form on the page. I navigate, inject my scripts, then fill out a form, and hit submit.

However, the form is a **standard post**, **not ajax**, and so everything **will be reloaded** by the browser.

What would be the best way to find out when the new page has actually reloaded?

The **loadAdapter** functionality will not be available then since I didn't navigate to the url using **loadURL()** but the page was reloaded within the browser itself.

I could manually sleep for a certain amount of time, however i'd like to know if there is a better solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the LoadAdapter for standard POST requests. Please take a look at the sample code below:

```
import com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.Browser;
import com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.events.FinishLoadingEvent;
import com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.events.FrameLoadEvent;
import com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.events.LoadAdapter;
import com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.swing.BrowserView;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;

public class LoadListenerSample {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final Browser browser = new Browser();
    BrowserView view = new BrowserView(browser);

    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.add(view, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    frame.setSize(800, 600);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);

    browser.addLoadListener(new LoadAdapter() {

        @Override
        public void onFinishLoadingFrame(FinishLoadingEvent event) {
            System.out.println("LoadListenerSample.onFinishLoadingFrame");
        }

        @Override
        public void onDocumentLoadedInFrame(FrameLoadEvent event) {
            System.out.println("LoadListenerSample.onDocumentLoadedInFrame");
        }


    });

    browser.loadURL("https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_form_submit");
}
}
```